# Turning off Offline Files & Folders for a roaming profile share

Tags: windows-server-2008, roaming-profile, offline-files

Here at work we have roaming profiles on one share, and redirected folders on another share.

When we configured these shares we did not know that you shouldn't enable the option ""All files and programs that users open from the share will be automatically available offline" on the share where the roaming profiles are located. Although it is fine to enable this on the share where the redirected folders are located.

We've been operating for quite a while now with this current configuration and for the *most* part it's been good. We do have the odd strange glitches which could be profile corruption.

In order to follow Microsoft's recommendations regarding roaming profiles I want to turn this automatic caching option on the share off. This is as per this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736881%28WS.10%29.aspx and many other sources (just search it).

My colleagues have warned me not to touch the setting however without extensive testing because last time it was turned off we had some problems for example like users not being able to log in to Windows when they were not connected to the work network.

Are these fears founded? Is it reasonable to expect problems if I turn the automatic caching off on the roaming profile share when we have had it on since 'the beginning'?

Comment: A detail that might be relevant; some clients are Windows XP Pro SP3 and some are Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, there should be no problems. But I agree with your colleagues: thoroughly test before changing the setting in production.